# Jhipster fast profile for tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, jhipster

starting tests is very slow process(like project using dev profile). For project I can use fast profile and it`s really faster. How can I use fast profile for tests? Maybe I can change database from H2 to Postgres(another database only for test) and then use this base. Or maybe create some new "fast" profile for test(but which different between dev and fast profile in structure). 
Thank you

Comment: If you maybe can, then maybe you should try that :-)

Comment: I thought, maybe someone already did it. But, if no - it will be my task)

Comment: The fastest test profile is one that skips them! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want use "fast" profile for tests like for application, you must open: `test.resources.config.application.yml` and add(redact) few strings:

```
spring:
    profiles:
        active: fast
    datasource:
```

After that, when you will try start tests - "fast" profile will be default profile for tests and will work with H2.